# App Doesn't fetch any records from iCloud after downloading from TestFlight

Tags: cloudkit, testflight

I have finished building my app and i submitted it to `TestFlight` for testing by internal users, however after downloading it, it doesn't fetch any data from iCloud, i'm using `CloudKit` and when i run it in `Xcode 9`, it works perfect and everything is fetched, however after submission and downloading from `TestFlight`, the `TableViews` are empty which is weird and have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: TestFlight uses the production iCloud database while your development testing uses the development iCloud database. Did you properly setup your production iCloud database using the iCloud dashboard? Did you populate any needed data into production?

Comment: oh i didn't even know, i was only using the development one, i have seen i have to deploy it to production